# What is curl of curl of displacement in spherical coordinate system?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, education

-1

I want to know what is the expression for curl of curl of u([rho],[Phi],[Theta]) (displacement) in spherical coordinate system. Assume it is 3D. So I wanted t calculate it by Mathematica but I'm not sure how I can get such answers. i want it parametrically.
In the below link, I provided a picture of curl of u. i guess for the start, i have to get one curl to get to the picture below for just one curl of vector u.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqwJW.png

In the below picture, I provided an answer that I find close to the next curl operation on vector u. However, i know that dimensions in the picture below is wrong and my ultimate goal in using Mathematica is to solve it in the program to check and correct the answer, provided as picture below. I would really appreciate any help.

https://ibb.co/dpFYCzH

Comment: What book is this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
Curl[Curl[{f[r, θ, ϕ], g[r, θ, ϕ], 
h[r, θ, ϕ]}, {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"] // 
 Expand, {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"] // Expand
```

results in

> $$\left.-\frac{f^{(0,2,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}-\frac{\cot (\theta ) f^{(0,1,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}-\frac{\csc ^2(\theta ) f^{(0,0,2)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}+\frac{g^{(0,1,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}+\frac{g^{(1,1,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+\frac{\cot (\theta ) g^{(1,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+\frac{\cot (\theta ) g(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}+\frac{\csc (\theta ) h^{(0,0,1)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}+\frac{\csc (\theta ) h^{(1,0,1)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r},\frac{f^{(1,1,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}-\frac{\csc ^2(\theta ) g^{(0,0,2)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}-g^{(2,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )-\frac{2 g^{(1,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+\frac{\csc (\theta ) h^{(0,1,1)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}+\frac{\cot (\theta ) \csc (\theta ) h^{(0,0,1)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2},\frac{\csc (\theta ) f^{(1,0,1)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+\frac{\csc (\theta ) g^{(0,1,1)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}-\frac{\cot (\theta ) \csc (\theta ) g^{(0,0,1)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}-\frac{h^{(0,2,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}-\frac{\cot (\theta ) h^{(0,1,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}-h^{(2,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )-\frac{2 h^{(1,0,0)}(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r}+\frac{\csc ^2(\theta ) h(r,\theta ,\phi )}{r^2}\right\} $$

Answer (score 3):

```
curll[v_, coo_ : {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}] := 
   Nest[(Curl[#, coo, "Spherical"] &), v, 2]    


   curll[{ vr[ \[Theta], \[Phi]], 0, 0}] /. 
      {r -> 1} //Simplify
```

$$\left\{-\text{vr}^{(2,0)}(\theta ,\phi )-\cot (\theta ) \text{vr}^{(1,0)}(\theta ,\phi )-\csc ^2(\theta ) \text{vr}^{(0,2)}(\theta ,\phi ),0,0\right\}$$